# OrientDB 2.0.3 Enterprise Workbench

Tags: orientdb

I have played a while with the new free enterprise edition of OrientDB 2.0.3 Server and Workbench on a Windows 8.1 machine. The OrientDB dserver.bat works fine and I can access it and work from localhost:2480. But when I launch the file start-workbench.bat I get this error:

```
2015-02-27 16:18:25:828 INFO  Profiler is recording metrics with configuration: 60,24
[OEnterpriseProfiler]Error on installing dynamic plugin 'enterprise-agent'
```

orientdb-enterprise-2-0-3 and orientdb-workbench-2.0.3 are sibling folders. Also tried to put agent-2.0.3.jar in the workbench plugins subfolder with no success. Should I work on config files?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. I have agent-2.0.3.jar in orientdb-enterprise-2.0.3/plugins folder but I can't see plugin is installed after server startup (there is only information about installing orientdb-lucene-2.0.3 and studio-2.0)

Comment: the agent-2.0.3.jar should be in the orientdb-enterprise-2.0.3/plugins folder. Do you have the startup logs?

Comment: Can you try on Linux to see if is a Windows problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully started OrientDB 2.0.3 Workbench via shell script `start-workbench.sh`, but I had to edit the last line to

> exec "$JAVA"...and the rest left the same

Before there were apostrophes and `exec` command missing. Now Workbench is running on url `http://10.0.0.41:2491`.